# Is it possible to reuse type parameter of generics of some class

Tags: typescript, generics, types, extract

For example I have following code

```
    class Foo {
      bar: Promise<string[]>;

      // a is the same type as type of promise in bar 
      baz(a: ????): Foo['bar'] {
        // some code
        return Promise.resolve(a);
      } 
    }
```

I can get type of bar - but I would like to get the type inside promise without creating extra type or interface.

I've searched a lot and I think this is not implemented or suggested yet, but before creating feature request I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but you will need a conditional type to extract the type parameter from the generic class via [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type UnboxPromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;
class Foo {
    bar: Promise<string[]>;

    // a is the same type as type of promise in bar 
    baz(a: UnboxPromise<Foo['bar']>): Foo['bar'] {
        // some code
        return Promise.resolve(a);
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgIwPYA8AKAnJBbAlgZwgB4AVKCFYCOAE3ykxwOIEM4QA+DqAXijIpVa9RnkJFccAGYQMsbgH5YUAFxQ4EAG6yA3ACgAxgBsW+egDEkSKAG89UB1AQsMa0cyL5gGSQHMA2gC6HPr2jgD04VAsUARQwAAW0Pgs2NCgkNH0GdBIUlBgWGLQkk4uUGEOzgBeABQsavDI6EUelkj+AOTOGJ3BAJRq7V09fbaVjg6RUPg40AZINBATkxgQwACuGHAMrYQAdGuzRtr1-fqTAL56l0A)

Comment: @Senyaak you can move the code to the parameter: but `a: Foo['bar'] extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never` is not an easy read: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=9&pln=6&pc=59#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgIwPYA8AKAnJBbAlgZwgB4AVKCFYCOAE3ykxwOIEM4QA+DqAXijIpVa9RnkJFccAGYQMsbgH5YUAFxQ4EAG6yA3ACgAxgBsW+egDEkSKAG89UB1AQsMa0cyL5gGSQHMA2gC6HPr2jgD04VAsUARQwAAW0Pgs2NCgkNH0GdBIUlBgWGLQkk4uUGEOzgBeABQsapZI-gDkzhgtgeSU1HQMRR6SMnIwispqGtoYAJSNVq3tnbaVjg6RUPg40AZINBArqxgQwACuGHD9TIQAdEebRtr10-qrAL56r0A

Comment: That what I have been looking for. Thank you. 
Anyway I think it would be useful if we could just directly extract type from generics.

Comment: @Senyaak If `Promise` would have a a member such as result we could use type queries  `Foo['bar']['result']`. So for some generic classes you can make this simpler, but nor for `Promise`